# actionlistener not working

Tags: java, button, jbutton

I am getting an error when trying to call the method getuserinput. Here is my bit of the code that is broken.

```
initialvelocitybutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        getuserinput(); //I am getting an error saying "The method getuserinput() is undefined for the type new ActionListener(){}"
           }
        });

static void getuserinput(){   //method to get users input
                double initialvelocity = Double.parseDouble(
                           JOptionPane.showInputDialog("please enter initial velocity")); //gets initial value of intiial velcoity
                double angleoflaunch = Double.parseDouble(
                           JOptionPane.showInputDialog("please enter angle of launch"));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`getuserInput()` is declared as `static`. You have to reference it using the class name: `NameOfYourClass.getuserInput();`

Comment: Sorry but I am not sure what my class name is. I tried Main.getusername();, I tried actionPerformed.getuserinput();...could u explain a bit more please

Comment: @user1183685 It may be time to [review some basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html).

Comment: That is the word between the `class` keyword and following `{` symbol in source code somewhere above the methods you've pasted. It is likely that the same is used as name of your source code file. More on declaring classes in Java tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classdecl.html

Comment: If you are using some IDE just search for the function and the class name will be the root.